# Erlang shell autocomplete not working on windows

Tags: windows, shell, autocomplete, erlang

When I'm opening erlang shell(in cmd or git bash), and try to use tab for autocomplete, it's just indenting. Can I make somehow make autocomplete working?

Answer (score 0):

https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html :

> Windows users probably want to use [the werl program](https://erlang.org/doc/man/werl.html) instead, which
> runs in its own window with scrollbars and ***supports command-line
> editing***. The erl program on Windows provides no line editing in its
> shell [...].

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be [fixed](https://www.erlang.org/news/164#the-shell) as of 26.0.

> This makes the Windows Erlang terminal experience identical to that of Unix.